# Transform list into dictonary with counter values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list, containing project names:

`my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'a']`

I want to put the letters into a dictonary, with the key values containing the number, for how many time a letter is in a list:

```
my_dict = {'a' : 4, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 1, 'd' : 1}
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: are you sure the list is as written, not `['a', 'b', …`?

Comment: yeah, it's like that. sorry, I've ment to correct it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is for:

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'a']
>>> Counter(my_list)
Counter({'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```